# how to fix "Error: Cannot find module './src/bot/index'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, ejs

When I write node src/index.js

I take this error
`Error: Cannot find module './src/bot/index' Require stack: C:\Users\MIMAR\Desktop\EJS\src\index.js`

Why I get this error?

src/index.js

https://paste.ee/p/UjnbR

Please help i tried everything

rebuild nodejs

rebuild all modules

[my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpCiI.png)

Comment: Please include all your code and your file structure

Comment: Can you add your code for better clarification

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

node src/index.js executes the index inside the src dir, since you are trying to import './src/bot/index' it means that your structure should look like
src>src>bot>index.js, which I doubt so, try changing it to import "./bot/index"

Comment: No , I have a file named src
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpCiI.png)--> My file structure